# possibility overwrite a rostopic?

Tags: rosnode, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a node(new_node) such that it should listen to a topic, process the topic further and should publish the edited topic in the same old name. But this should be written as a seperate node.

So, Is it possible to overwrite a rostopic ?

Note: When I run the new_node, only one topic should be published in the same name?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45587/possibility-overwrite-a-rostopic?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node can publish on the same topic it listens to, but it cannot prevent all other nodes from getting both old and new messages.

Depending on what exactly you  are trying to achieve, different solutions are possible.

If you know you just have one original node publishing, then you could remap the topic of that published node to a new custom topic. Your custom node can then listen on the custom topic, and publish messages on the original topic.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3